# Is there any way to embed tables from excel that have pull down menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat, data-validation

I may not be using the correct terminoloby, but, here goes. We have setup an Excel spreadsheet that is formatted into multiple 8.5 x 11 pages on one tab. The spread sheet has tables with a pull down menu on some of the pages. Once you select an option from the pull down menu, it automatically prefills certain tables on other related pages within that tab.

Is there any way to embed this spreadsheet into an Acrobat 8 PDF page and still have it function?

We are trying to create a makeshift "quoting system" so that people can find rates specific to them.

We set up the brochure in a page layout program for design purposes and then exported that to a PDF. Now we would like to embed the Excel tables into the PDF page and still have the pull-down menu and pre-fill options function.

Is there any way to do this? We are using Acrobat 8.

Comment: have you tried to `save as - pdf`? What happens when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the answer is no.

Someone created these spreadsheets by programming in Visual Basic for Applications or by creating some very complex formulas.  That's the only way that Excel could do something so specifically customized as to fill some of the "tables" based on your selection in a drop down list.  Because the VBA code (or a formula) is interpreted and executed by the Excel program, there is no way that these functions will work outside of Excel.

Making a PDF file is essentially just "taking a picture" of the current state of the sheet.  Even a simple formula in an Excel spreadsheet won't recalculate in a PDF file of that spreadsheet.  What you are describing is much more complex than a basic formula.

Workable options for distributing your "quoting system" would be to provide users who don't have Excel installed a copy of one of the [free Excel alternatives](http://bit.ly/yISZa1), recreate the spreadsheet in a free share-able Google Docs spreadsheet, or create a web page with equivalent functionality.